# Global Exception Handling in Spring Cloud Function on AWS Lambda Platform

Tags: spring, aws-lambda, cloud, spring-cloud

I am using spring cloud function on AWS lambda. I am trying to achieve global exception handling like Spring Boot using @ExceptionHandler annotation. But this method is not getting executed and I am getting 500 for any type of exception.
Sample code is below-

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
       SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public Function<Message<User>, User> getUser(){
            return (message)->{
                    User u = message.getPayload();
                    if(u==null){
                          throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,"No user details provided");
                    } 
                 return u;
            }
      }
   @ExceptionHandler(ResponseStatusException.class)
   public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleException(ResponseStatusException e){
      APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent response = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent();
      response.setStatusCode(e.getRawStatusCode());
      response.setBody(e.getMessage());
     return response;
   }
}
```

I am getting 500 in response instead **Bad Request**. Is there any way to achieve this scenario ?

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide your custom exceptionHandler while building SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.

```
public class StreamLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {

  private static SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;

  static {
    handler = new SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder<AwsProxyRequest>()
            .defaultProxy()
            .exceptionHandler(***your customer handler here***)
            // other methods are skipped
            .buildAndInitialize();  
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. But its too late. I switched to plain java with hibernate along with AWS Lambda. Lots of complications was with spring and AWS lambda. I think spring with lambda is bad choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring cloud functions no need to use `SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler`, what you need to do is create a custom routing function and handle the exception thrown from your lambda function and return APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent. below shows how I achieved the desired result

```
public class CustomRoutingFunction implements Function<Message<?>, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent> {

private final FunctionCatalog functionCatalog;

private final FunctionProperties functionProperties;

private final MessageRoutingCallback routingCallback;

public static final String DEFAULT_ROUTE_HANDLER = "defaultMessageRoutingHandler";


public CustomRoutingFunction(FunctionCatalog functionCatalog,
                             FunctionProperties functionProperties,
                             MessageRoutingCallback routingCallback) {
    this.functionCatalog = functionCatalog;
    this.functionProperties = functionProperties;
    this.routingCallback = routingCallback;
}

@Override
public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent apply(Message<?> input) {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    try {
        String functionDefinition = this.routingCallback.routingResult(input);
        SimpleFunctionRegistry.FunctionInvocationWrapper function = functionCatalog.lookup(functionDefinition);
        Object output = function.apply(input);

        String payload = mapper.writeValueAsString(output);

        return new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent()
                .withIsBase64Encoded(false)
                .withBody(payload)
                .withHeaders(Map.of(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                        "statusCode", "200"))
                .withStatusCode(200);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent()
                .withIsBase64Encoded(false)
                .withHeaders(Map.of(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,
                        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                        "statusCode", String.valueOf(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value())))
                .withBody(e.getMessage())
                .withStatusCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
    }
  }
}
```

now you need to register your router function as a bean and pass it to `spring.cloud.function.definition`

```
@Bean
public CustomRoutingFunction customRoutingFunction(FunctionCatalog functionCatalog,
                                                   FunctionProperties functionProperties,
                                                   @Nullable MessageRoutingCallback routingCallback,
                                                   @Nullable DefaultMessageRoutingHandler defaultMessageRoutingHandler) {
    if (defaultMessageRoutingHandler != null) {
        FunctionRegistration functionRegistration = new FunctionRegistration(defaultMessageRoutingHandler, CustomRoutingFunction.DEFAULT_ROUTE_HANDLER);
        functionRegistration.type(FunctionTypeUtils.consumerType(ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(Message.class, Object.class).getType()));
        ((FunctionRegistry) functionCatalog).register(functionRegistration);
    }
    return new CustomRoutingFunction(functionCatalog, functionProperties, routingCallback);
}
```

inside your application.yml file

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: customRoutingFunction
```